# time precision in geopandas read_file

Tags: python, geopandas

Geopandas `read_file` reads my time field with less precision. How can I make it the same as my file?

I created a file with geopandas `to_file(filename, driver='GeoJSON')` and it is something like this:

`{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "LineaRuta": "A", "Time": "2018-06-25 11:57:55.537" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 505529.0, 4788595.0 ] }`

I read it with `read_file(filename, driver='GeoJSON')` and the time (datetime) losses its millisecond precision:

`LineaRuta     Time                 geometry
0     A        2018-06-25T11:48:09  POINT (506375 4790366)`

I tried to see if it is changing the format with:

`schema = gpd.io.file.infer_schema(data2)
print(schema)`

But the output says that it is string type. Then why it reads like a datetime? Output:
`{'geometry': 'Point', 'properties': OrderedDict([('LineaRuta', 'str'), ('Time', 'str')])}`

I need the millisecond precision in the time field, is there any easy way to do it? For example with fiona's read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you write or read your file the time column is considered as a string.
You can use `strptime` from `datetime` library to convert it as a datetime object

```
gdf = gpd.read_file(your_file, driver='GeoJSON')
gdf['date'] = gdf['your_date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

Here is a reference to datetime formats http://strftime.org/

Comment: But this is to format it to the way I want, but the information of milliseconds is already lost in `read_file`, right? What I would like is to read it maintaining all the info of the strings (also with milliseconds). Question edited for better understanding

Comment: @AurelieNavir Does it behave the same way if you replace '.' by ',' for the miliseconds before saving the file ?

Comment: Yes, it cuts the milliseconds too. Maybe if I change completely the format geopandas will not know? Also, there is not an easier way to define the time format reading the file?

Comment: @AurelieNavir What if you switch to a csv file ? to force it read the time column as a string

Comment: I tried to change the datime format a little bit more and it works. The format I tried: `%Y_%m_%d_%H:%M:%S.%f`. I guess you can also use csv format, but from what I read, it is not implemented to use directly with geopandas right? Thx for all